# Recommended naming conventions for class-members: Stick to "STANDARD" or to "WORLD's best practices"?

Tags: abap

So, the topic says it all.
It is simply about how to prefix/suffix/mark special types of class members.
As we can see in sap-standard, there is no real convention, either, because of no existing guidelines, or because of too much developers or because of outsourcing to other companies, which might have their own. Of course this might become an "opinion" based discussion, so please forgive. Nevertheless I would like to hear some pro's and cons, and in this case we are only dealing with ABAP-OO.

What would You recommend / have seen mostly used / is entitled as best practice for nearly all  kind's of class-members, like these, for example:

- public instance methods ( ALSO GETTERS / SETTERS )
- protected instance methods
- private instance methods
- public static methods
- protected static methods
- private static methods
- public instance attribute TABLES ( include kind of table if you want )
- protected instance attribute TABLES
- private instance attribute TABLES
- -->All the above stuff also for structures and simple datatypes
- static public constants
- static private constants
- interface-members

I am on my search for a most common denominator to extract those, which convention would fit best into abap-oo and also might be near to world's 
conventions of other languages. 
Obviously we can say, that hungarian notation can be said as being obsolete
(means, that an instance table does not really need a "*T*" and a structure does not really need a "*S*" somewhere in their prefizes. But, according to other languages, a private counter could be named
_instance_counter, what I personally prefer).

I am already surprised by all the sap-"standard" differences, now I would like to wait for some of You.

Comment: Keep cool with downvoting. I wrote, that this might be opinion based. I do not want collecting opinions but best-practices.

Comment: But is the definition of _best_ not also biased ?

Comment: Best practices should not be subjective.

Comment: Everything that takes a plural is disputable ;-) I can argue that my preferred best practice is better than your. But nevermind.

Comment: Then post just some of Yours. Why not ? practice(S) because of all the members to prefix/suffix/mark.

Comment: Hello, guys? It is still an invitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP-Press has actually published a set of ABAP development guidelines.

[Official ABAP development guidelines](https://www.sap-press.com/official-abap-programming-guidelines_2093/)

Highlights include:

- Separation of concerns
- Program type and attributes
- Checks for accuracy
- Code formatting and organization
- Comments and alternative notation
- Error handling
- Data storage
- Data types and objects
- Calculations and accesses
- Fields and tables
- Modularization
- Dynamic programming

We could argue best practise until we're blue in the face, but in the end all you really want is consistency.

When I start at a new client I always ask for THEIR development standards, whether I agree with their standards or not isn't really relevant. However,  people are usually open for discussion if you present a reasoned argument.